# Add a template from a non-storefront cartridge to Demandware Content Slot Configuration?

Tags: demandware

I'm using the Demandware Business Manager to create a new content slot configuration for a pre-existing content slot following the Demandware DiD Instructor Guide (pg. 152). My issue is that I'm being told to add a content slot configuration to "merchant-product" using a template that is in the "training" cartridge.  However, when I try to add a template, the pop up (from clicking [...]) only allows me to view templates that are within the storefront cartridge.

This template is in the "training" cartridge because the instructions indicated to put it in the "training" cartridge instead of the "storefront" cartridge.  I have included the "training" cartridge in my site settings as per the instructions.  Why does this cartridge not appear as an available cartridge to use templates from?

How do I add this (non-storefront) cartridge in so that I may use a template from it?

Comment: When the `training` cartridge is already on the cartridge path, check if the template is in the right place: it has to be under `<cartridge>/templates/slots/<type>` where `type` matches what you have selected for the slot config type (product, asset, ...).

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the instruction below.

- Go to your Sandbox - Business Manager.
- On the left nav, navigate to Sites -> Manage Sites -> [Select your
  Site/Store Name e.g. SiteGenesis]
- Click on it, then you will see some tabs some as General, Settings,
  Cache, and Security.
- Go click Settings tab.
- On the Cartridges text field, you will something like this:

> sitegenesis_storefront_richUI:sitegenesis_storefront_core

- Add your cartridge name having this separation of colon symbol.
- Saves Changes and apply.
- Make sure to clean your cache after doing this.

Try again to access your cartridge outside of storefront app and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To solve please copy slots folder under templates/default/ folder.